# While loops with Sentinels for Java

Tags: java, while-loop, sentinel

I am writing the following program using while loops with sentinels.
The problems I am having include:
(1) Discovering how to obtain the "smallest score" entered without the value equaling the sentinel.
(2) Obtain the "largest score" and "smallest score" when only one integer is entered.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. The following is the details of the program:

```
//Write a program that inputs a series of exam scores as integers.
//The number of scores is not limited.
//Print the number of scores entered and the largest and smallest score entered. 
//Use a sentinel to terminate the input.
    //Input: Series of exam scores as integers.
    //Output: Number of scores entered and the largest and smallest score entered.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class hwk_6_1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int exam_score;
        int number_of_scores = 0;
        int i;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter exam score or -1 to end: ");
        exam_score = keyboard.nextInt();

        int largest_score = 0;
        int smallest_score = 0;

        while(exam_score != -1) {
            for(i = 0; i < i + exam_score; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter exam score or -1 to end: ");
                exam_score = keyboard.nextInt();
                number_of_scores = i;

                if(exam_score > largest_score) {
                    largest_score = exam_score;
                }
                if(exam_score < smallest_score) {
                    smallest_score = exam_score;
                }
            }
        }  
        System.out.println("The number of scores entered: " + (number_of_scores + 1) + ".");
        System.out.println("Largest score: " + largest_score + ".");
        System.out.println("Smallest score: " + smallest_score + ".");
    }
}
```

Note: we are not supposed to use an 'if' to check for the sentinel, only a while loop; do not use exit or break. Also, we are to be sure to use a sentinel value and two read statements. Code for this program should be similar to the following algorithm:

```
read data // first data 
while not last data {
    process data
    read data 
}
```

Comment: Your code is highly confusing. You should **not** be using something that is called "exam_score" to define the **number of loop operations** you intend to run. Probably that is your problem - there is absolutely no sense in that condition i < i + exam_score.

Answer (score 1):

You are not following your pseudocode, this is what you want:

```
read data // first data 
while not last data{
process data
read data 
}
```

And this is what you have:

```
read data // first data 
while not last data{
read data  // <-- you are reading again and ignoring the first value
process data 
}
```

You need to process the data and read the next data at the end of the loop to follow your target pseudocode.

Also, this condition can be improved:

```
for(i = 0; i < i + exam_score; i++)
```

You don't need to use `i` in the condition, you only need to check if exam score is `-1`, so it could be:

```
for(i = 0; exam_score != -1; i++)
```

There is also a problem with the count of scores, you are setting `numer_of_scores` to `i`. After the first iteration you set the value to 0 and you have read two scores. Its better to use `number_of_scores++` after each read and don't use `i` at all.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int exam_score;
    int number_of_scores = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter exam score or -1 to end: ");
    exam_score = keyboard.nextInt();

    int largest_score = 0;
    int smallest_score = 0;

    while(exam_score != -1)
    {
        number_of_scores++;

        if(exam_score > largest_score)
        {
          largest_score = exam_score;
        }
        if(exam_score < smallest_score)
        {
          smallest_score = exam_score;
        } 
        System.out.print("Enter exam score or -1 to end: ");
        exam_score = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("The number of scores entered: " + number_of_scores + ".");
    System.out.println("Largest score: " + largest_score + ".");
    System.out.println("Smallest score: " + smallest_score + ".");
}
```

Comment: Hint: there is no sense in using that for loop there (i isn't used anyway); so why not just go with one (while) loop?! You might want to mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ David SN: Super helpful, thank you ever so much. The increment recommendation as well as taking out the for loop totally helped. 
@ GhostCat: Thank you, taking out the for loop helped make this program simple.

I ran into another issue with the program which was finding the proper value for the smallest_score. Since the sentinel is technically less than the initial value of the smallest score (i.e. `smallest_score = 0` & `sentinel = -1`), the result of the smallest_score variable equals its initial value, 0. I tried assigning a really large value to the smallest_score variable, and it seems to work. As long as the exam_score values entered do not exceed the value of the smallest_score variable, the code seems to follow the program rules. So, same code as previously, but assign smallest_score variable an insanely large value, like 99999999999.

Thank you so much for all the help given. Greatly appreciated and I look forward to learning from you all.